# FTP file to a mainframe server with some data using sun.net.ftp.FtpClient java

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

Here I'm able to create an empty file in the mainframe with below code. How can I write some data to that file or write data in a file and then put it in the server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String serverName = "";
    String user = "";
    String passwd = "";

    openServer(serverName);
    login(user, passwd);

    Socket socketdata = openDataConnection("STOR 'fileName'");

    BufferedWriter outstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketdata.getOutputStream()));

    outstream.write("fileName");
    outstream.write("\r\n", 0, "\r\n".length());

    outstream.flush();

    socketdata.close();
    closeServer();
}
```

And just to mention, I intentionally removed the server name, user name and password. And also I should use sun.net.ftp.FtpClient package. So its not Apache commons net jar. Can any one help me.

**Edit**
The requirement is, there is a job in mainframes which has to be triggered with some data. I'm trying to send the data in a file and as soon as the file is placed, job is triggered and it takes data from file. Is there any other way we can achieve it with out any file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should not directly use any `sun.*` class. There has been an explicit warning about that in the Javadoc for 20 years: [Note about sun.* packages](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).

However you *can* do it via `new URL("ftp://...")`, get a `URLConnection` from it, get its output stream, and start writing. That will do a STOR to the target URL in binary mode.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. The requirement is, there is a job in mainframes which has to be triggered with some data. I'm trying to send the data in a file and as soon as the file is placed, job is triggered and it takes data from file. Is there any other way we can achieve it

Comment: @Krishna I do not understand you. I have given you another way you can achieve it.